# How to save files to none temp directory and view contents of files in that directory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

a)In my app I want to be able to save files to a directory where they will not disappear from while the app is installed. Where can I save them?

b)I also want to be able to look at all the files in a directory and have a table displaying them. Is there some method that can get the contents of a directory? Kind of like dir in DOS. Maybe returning an array of all the contents? Or something that I can then put into an array and make a table from it.

I know how to make a path to a temp dir:

```
NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), 
@"output.mov"];
NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputPath];
```

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the files in the documents directory:

```
NSArray  *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir  = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *outputPath    = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mov"];
```

It is generally not necessary to convert the file path to a URL.

Get the file list with the Filemanager method:

```
- (NSArray *)contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

Performs a shallow search of the specified directory and returns the paths of any contained items.

Return Value:

An array of NSString objects, each of which identifies a file, directory, or symbolic link contained in path. Returns an empty array if the directory exists but has no contents. If an error occurs, this method returns nil and assigns an appropriate error object to the error parameter

Answer (score 0):

On iPhone app you save contents to app document directory you can get path like the example:

```
NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docDirectory,@"output.mov"];
```